# Implementing a programming idea of random numbers and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am kind of new in programming generally and I found it a good idea to ask here first.

So, let's say I have about 900 sets of 6 numbers stored somewhere (maybe in arrays?). I want each time to generate a random set of 6 numbers that is different than the other 900. If it is the same (check with the other 900), then don't accept it and generate a new. I thought of using arrays and check the new set with the others each time, but I think it's a little "painful" to have 900 arrays before.

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to do with 900 arrays?!

Comment: you could use `in_array` http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php but that wouldn't be good for the performance... Thinking about a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I failed to imagine the task you need this for. )) But usually when you need to ensure a uniqueness of some sort of sets, you use hashes.

Let's say, for example, we have 900 arrays of the following structure:

```
$arr1 = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6];
$arr2 = [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6];
...
```

And we need another array, which shouldn't be the same as any of these.

The solution, I think, is to create a metastructure for storing these arrays alongside its hashes. Something like...

```
$arrayCollection = array(
  hash($arr1) => $arr1,
  hash($arr2) => $arr2,
  ...
);
```

Then, when a new set is created, I'd generate its hash too - and just check whether the element with the same hash already exists in my collection. Like this:

```
do {
  $newArr = generateArray();
  $newArrHash = hash($newArr);
} while (isset($arrayCollection[$newArrayHash]));
```

It would be quite fast, much faster then just comparing these sets again and again. )

As for `hash` function, it can be as simple as...

```
function hash(array $arr) {
  return implode('|', $arr);
}
```

... or you may need to wrap it into some digest function (`md5($x, true)` will do just fine, I suppose), if `$arr` may contain some very large strings/numbers.

Comment: Well it's something that came in my mind! :P how long would the hash be?

Comment: So that's like using a multidimensional array?